# Filter dataframe if pair of values are in list of list

Tags: r, filter, subset

I need to filter a dataframe related to students curriculum.

What I'm expecting to do, is getting all the rows where ([curr_code, course] not in combinations), where combinations is a list of list containing all the posible combinations to delete.

```
combinations <- list(
  hydraulics = list(cod = 81017, exp = list("ICH2304", "IMM2003")),
  cience = list(cod = 81016, exp = list("ICH2304")),
  data_science = list(cod = 81015, exp = list("IIC1005"))
)
```

And here's part of my data (exp_data):

```
id  curr_code  course
1   81017      ICH2304
2   81017      IMM2003
3   81017      IIC1005
4   81016      ICH2304
5   81015      ICH2304
6   81015      IIC1005
7   81015      IBM1005
```

I should get:

```
id  curr_code  course
1   81017      IIC1005
2   81015      ICH2304
3   81015      IBM1005
```

I tried using:

```
new_data <- filter(exp_data, !(list.any(combinations, (course %in% exp) && (cod == curr_code))))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, working with `combinations` as a nested list is going to make things complicated. Better, if possible, to have it as a tidy data.frame:

```
comb <- data.frame(name = c('hydraulics','hydraulics','cience','data_science'),
                   cod = c(81017, 81017, 81016, 81015),
                   exp = c("ICH2304", "IMM2003", "ICH2304", "IIC1005"))
comb
          name   cod     exp
1   hydraulics 81017 ICH2304
2   hydraulics 81017 IMM2003
3       cience 81016 ICH2304
4 data_science 81015 IIC1005
```

Now, we can loop through your `exp_data` by row and match up the values of `course` and `curr_code` with the values in `comb`. `which` will return the row number where that value is found. By taking the `intersect` of those, you get a vector with the row index of rowswhere **both** the `course` and `curr_code` match. If there are no matches, you'll get a empty vector.

Since we're looking for rows with no matches, we can just check if the `length` of that vector `== 0` to get a logical vector telling you which rows of `exp_data` have no matching rows in `comb`. We can simply use this vector to subset `exp_data` using square bracket notation to get our desired result.

```
rows_no_match <- apply(exp_data, 1, function(x) {
    length(intersect(which(x[['course']] == comb$exp),
                     which(x[['curr_code']] == comb$cod))) == 0
    })

exp_data[rows_no_match,]
  id curr_code  course
3  3     81017 IIC1005
5  5     81015 ICH2304
7  7     81015 IBM1005
```